# SSE _mm_movemask_epi8 equivalent method for ARM NEON

Tags: arm, sse, neon

I decided to continue Fast corners optimisation and stucked at
`_mm_movemask_epi8` SSE instruction. How can i rewrite it for ARM Neon with `uint8x16_t` input?

Comment: A version with 32-bit elements, e.g. after an FP compare [(NEON pack vector compare result into bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568992/neon-pack-vector-compare-result-into-bitmap).  3 instructions.  Like x86 `movmskps` instead of `pmovmskb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some tests it looks like following code works correct:

```
int32_t _mm_movemask_epi8_neon(uint8x16_t input)
{
    const int8_t __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) xr[8] = {-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0};
    uint8x8_t mask_and = vdup_n_u8(0x80);
    int8x8_t mask_shift = vld1_s8(xr);

    uint8x8_t lo = vget_low_u8(input);
    uint8x8_t hi = vget_high_u8(input);

    lo = vand_u8(lo, mask_and);
    lo = vshl_u8(lo, mask_shift);

    hi = vand_u8(hi, mask_and);
    hi = vshl_u8(hi, mask_shift);

    lo = vpadd_u8(lo,lo);
    lo = vpadd_u8(lo,lo);
    lo = vpadd_u8(lo,lo);

    hi = vpadd_u8(hi,hi);
    hi = vpadd_u8(hi,hi);
    hi = vpadd_u8(hi,hi);

    return ((hi[0] << 8) | (lo[0] & 0xFF));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this post is quite outdated but I found it useful to give my (validated) solution. It assumes all ones/all zeroes in every lane of the Input argument.

```
const uint8_t __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) _Powers[16]= 
    { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 };

// Set the powers of 2 (do it once for all, if applicable)
uint8x16_t Powers= vld1q_u8(_Powers);

// Compute the mask from the input
uint64x2_t Mask= vpaddlq_u32(vpaddlq_u16(vpaddlq_u8(vandq_u8(Input, Powers))));

// Get the resulting bytes
uint16_t Output;
vst1q_lane_u8((uint8_t*)&Output + 0, (uint8x16_t)Mask, 0);
vst1q_lane_u8((uint8_t*)&Output + 1, (uint8x16_t)Mask, 8);
```

(Mind http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47553, anyway.)

Similarly to Michael, the trick is to form the powers of the indexes of the non-null entries, and to sum them pairwise three times. This must be done with increasing data size to double the stride on every addition. You reduce from 2 x 8 8-bit entries to 2 x 4 16-bit, then 2 x 2 32-bit and 2 x 1 64-bit. The low byte of these two numbers gives the solution. I don't think there is an easy way to pack them together to form a single short value using NEON.

Takes 6 NEON instructions if the input is in the suitable form and the powers can be preloaded.

Comment: Do most ARM chips hit a store-forwarding stall if this compiles to 2 byte stores and one half-word reload?  Can't a vector shuffle put the low byte of each half of a 128-bit register into the low 2 bytes of that register?  If you're on 32-bit ARM, that means the bytes you want are at the bottom of two `d` registers that compose one `q` register, so can you zip them together to get the 2 bytes you want at the bottom of one `d` register?  Compilers would probably do a bad job if you did this with intrinsics, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, very helpful. I replaced the last two lines with Output = (uint16_t)(vst1q_lane_u64(Mask, 0) + (vst1q_lane_u64(Mask, 0) << 8));  That seems to be much faster and doesn't assume little endianness (well, for those extra rare cases of big endian NEONs).

Comment: Sorry, vgetq_lane_u64(), obviously.

Comment: @David, tried your solution replacing the last two lines (using `vgetq_lane_u64`) and the output seems to be incorrect

Comment: @mwag, Thank you, I don't really remember this exact details and unfortunately I could not find it in the code that used it because I ended up ditching this approach all together and solving my specific issue in a completely different way. 
You are probably right, thank you for warning others as well :)

Answer (score 5):

The obvious solution seems to be completely missed here.

```c
// Use shifts to collect all of the sign bits.
// I'm not sure if this works on big endian, but big endian NEON is very
// rare.
int vmovmaskq_u8(uint8x16_t input)
{
    // Example input (half scale):
    // 0x89 FF 1D C0 00 10 99 33

    // Shift out everything but the sign bits
    // 0x01 01 00 01 00 00 01 00
    uint16x8_t high_bits = vreinterpretq_u16_u8(vshrq_n_u8(input, 7));

    // Merge the even lanes together with vsra. The '??' bytes are garbage.
    // vsri could also be used, but it is slightly slower on aarch64.
    // 0x??03 ??02 ??00 ??01
    uint32x4_t paired16 = vreinterpretq_u32_u16(
                              vsraq_n_u16(high_bits, high_bits, 7));
    // Repeat with wider lanes.
    // 0x??????0B ??????04
    uint64x2_t paired32 = vreinterpretq_u64_u32(
                              vsraq_n_u32(paired16, paired16, 14));
    // 0x??????????????4B
    uint8x16_t paired64 = vreinterpretq_u8_u64(
                              vsraq_n_u64(paired32, paired32, 28));
    // Extract the low 8 bits from each lane and join.
    // 0x4B
    return vgetq_lane_u8(paired64, 0) | ((int)vgetq_lane_u8(paired64, 8) << 8);
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Compiles for ARM and AArch64: https://godbolt.org/z/-UfPYD.  I don't know what `vsra` does, though, and this answer doesn't explain it.  I assume it's a right-shift and accumulate.

Comment: Correct. Shifts right and adds. [Here is a diagram of the operation in binary.](https://i.imgur.com/pulGGXT.png)

Answer (score 2):

This question deserves a newer answer for aarch64. The addition of new capabilities to Armv8 allows the same function to be implemented in fewer instructions. Here's my version:

```
uint32_t _mm_movemask_aarch64(uint8x16_t input)
{   
    const uint8_t __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) ucShift[] = {-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0};
    uint8x16_t vshift = vld1q_u8(ucShift);
    uint8x16_t vmask = vandq_u8(input, vdupq_n_u8(0x80));
    uint32_t out;
    
    vmask = vshlq_u8(vmask, vshift);
    out = vaddv_u8(vget_low_u8(vmask));
    out += (vaddv_u8(vget_high_u8(vmask)) << 8);
    
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is here for 8 years already but let me give you the answer which might solve all performance problems with emulation. It's based on the blog [Bit twiddling with Arm Neon: beating SSE movemasks, counting bits and more](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/infrastructure-solutions-blog/posts/porting-x86-vector-bitmask-optimizations-to-arm-neon).

Most usages of movemask instructions are coming from comparisons where the vectors have **0xFF** or **0x00** values from the result of every 16 bytes. After that most cases to use movemasks are to check if none/all match, find leading/trailing or iterate over bits.

If this is the case which often is, then you can use `shrn reg1, reg2, #4` instruction. This instruction called **Sh**ift-**R**ight-then-**N**arrow instruction can reduce a 128-bit byte mask to a 64-bit nibble mask (by alternating low and high nibbles to the result). This allows the mask to be extracted to a 64-bit general purpose register.

```
const uint16x8_t equalMask = vreinterpretq_u16_u8(vceqq_u8(chunk, vdupq_n_u8(tag)));
const uint8x8_t res = vshrn_n_u16(equalMask, 4);
const uint64_t matches = vget_lane_u64(vreinterpret_u64_u8(res), 0);
return matches;
```

After that you can use all bit operations you typically use on x86 with very minor tweaks like shifting by 2 or doing a scalar AND.

[image]

Comment: This is only useful on AArch64.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I haven't tested any of this, but something like this might work:

```
X := the vector that you want to create the mask from
A := 0x808080808080...
B := 0x00FFFEFDFCFB...  (i.e. 0,-1,-2,-3,...)

X = vand_u8(X, A);  // Keep d7 of each byte in X
X = vshl_u8(X, B);  // X[7]>>=0; X[6]>>=1; X[5]>>=2; ...
// Each byte of X now contains its msb shifted 7-N bits to the right, where N
// is the byte index.
// Do 3 pairwise adds in order to pack all these into X[0]
X = vpadd_u8(X, X); 
X = vpadd_u8(X, X); 
X = vpadd_u8(X, X);
// X[0] should now contain the mask. Clear the remaining bytes if necessary
```

This would need to be repeated once to process a 128-bit vector, since `vpadd` only works on 64-bit vectors.

Comment: hi @Michael thanx for the example. can u please explain how can i fill vector B with required bytes? for A i can use vdup_n_u8(0x80) but how should i do it for A? also u u write vshl_u8 but in comment there is shift right?

Comment: To initialize vector B: `vld1` from a const array(?).   About the right shift: the ARM documentation states _"If the shift value is positive, the operation is a left shift. Otherwise, it is a right shift."_. I'm not entirely sure if that's the case if the data you shift is `u8`, or if you need to use `s8`.

Comment: yep i understand that i need to load B from an array i was just wondering about supplied values in that vector. can u be more specific about it? should be just [0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7]? and yes i need it for u8 data vector at the moment

Comment: Yes, 0..-7. Another possibility would be to replace the `vand`/`vshl` with a `vcge` (where you compare against vector A) followed by a `vand` where you AND against 0x8040201008040201.