# Suggestion in ARM NEON optimization

Tags: optimization, assembly, arm, neon

For academic purposes I want to try to write an ARM NEON optimization of the following algorithm, even only to test if it is possible to obtain any performance improvement or not. I think this is not a good candidate for SIMD optimization because results are merged togheter losing parallelization gains.

This is the algorithm:

```
const uchar* center = ...;

int t0, t1, val;
t0 = center[0]; t1 = center[1];
val = t0 < t1;
t0 = center[2]; t1 = center[3];
val |= (t0 < t1) << 1;
t0 = center[4]; t1 = center[5];
val |= (t0 < t1) << 2;
t0 = center[6]; t1 = center[7];
val |= (t0 < t1) << 3;
t0 = center[8]; t1 = center[9];
val |= (t0 < t1) << 4;
t0 = center[10]; t1 = center[11];
val |= (t0 < t1) << 5;
t0 = center[12]; t1 = center[13];
val |= (t0 < t1) << 6;
t0 = center[14]; t1 = center[15];
val |= (t0 < t1) << 7;

d[i] = (uchar)val;
```

This is what I thought in ARM assembly:

```
VLD2.8 {d0, d1} ["center" addr]
```

supposing 8 bit chars, this first operation should load all the t0 and t1 values alternatively in 2 registers.

```
VCLT.U8 d2, d0, d1
```

a single operation of "less then" for all the comparisons. NOTES: I've read that VCLT is possible only with a #0 constant as second operand, so this must be inverted in a >=. Reading ARM documentation i think the result of every 8 bit value will be "all 1" for true (11111111) or "all 0" for false (00000000).

```
VSHR.U8 d4, d2, #7
```

this right shift will delete 7 out of 8 values in the register 8-bit "cells" (mainly to delete 7 ones). I've used d4 because of the next step will be the first d register mapped in q2.

Now problems begin: shifting and ORs.

```
VSHLL.U8 q2[1], d4[1], 1
VSHLL.U8 q2[2], d4[2], 2
...
VSHLL.U8 q2[7], d4[7], 7
```

I can imagine only this way (if it's possible to use [offsets]) for left shifts. Q2 should be specified instead of d4 according to the documentation.

```
VORR(.U8) d4[0], d4[1], d4[0]
VORR(.U8) d4[0], d4[2], d4[0]
...
VORR(.U8) d4[0], d4[7], d4[0]
```

Last step should give the result.

```
VST1.8 d4[0], [d[i] addr]
```

Simple store of the result.

It is my first approach to ARM NEON, so probably many assumptions may be incorrect. Help me understand possible errors, and suggest a better solution if possible.

**EDIT:**
This is the final working code after the suggested solutions:

```
__asm__ __volatile ("VLD2.8 {d0, d1}, [%[ordered_center]] \n\t"
"VCGT.U8 d2, d1, d0 \n\t"
"MOV r1, 0x01 \n\t"
"MOV r2, 0x0200 \n\t"
"ORR r2, r2, r1 \n\t"
"MOV r1, 0x10 \n\t"
"MOV r3, 0x2000 \n\t"
"ORR r3, r3, r1 \n\t"
"MOVT r2, 0x0804 \n\t"
"MOVT r3, 0x8040 \n\t"
"VMOV.32 d3[0], r2 \n\t"
"VMOV.32 d3[1], r3 \n\t"
"VAND d0, d2, d3 \n\t"
"VPADDL.U8 d0, d0 \n\t"
"VPADDL.U16 d0, d0 \n\t"
"VPADDL.U32 d0, d0 \n\t"
"VST1.8 d0[0], [%[desc]] \n\t"
:
: [ordered_center] "r" (ordered_center), [desc] "r" (&desc[i])
: "d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "r1", "r2", "r3");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870910/sse-mm-movemask-epi8-equivalent-method-for-arm-neon not sure why this doesn't show up as linked when it's quoted in an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comparison, you have an array of 8 booleans represented by `0xff` or `0x00`.  The reason SIMD comparisons (on any architecture) produce those values is to make them useful for a bit-mask operation (and/or bit-select in NEON's case) so you can turn the result into an arbitrary value quickly, without a multiply.

So rather than reducing them to `1` or `0` and shifting them about, you'll find it easier to mask them with the constant `0x8040201008040201`.  Then each lane contains the bit corresponding to its position in the final result.  You can pre-load the constant into another register (I'll use `d3`).

```
VAND d0, d2, d3
```

Then, to combine the results, you can use `VPADD` (instead of `OR`), which will combine adjacent pairs of lanes, `d0[0] = d0[0] + d0[1]`, `d0[1] = d0[2] + d0[3]`, etc...  Since the bit patterns do not overlap there is no carry and add works just as well as or.  Also, because the output is half as large as the input we have to fill in the second half with junk.  I've used a second copy of `d0` for that.

You'll need to do the add three times to get all columns combined.

```
VPADD.u8 d0, d0, d0
VPADD.u8 d0, d0, d0
VPADD.u8 d0, d0, d0
```

and now the result will now be in `d0[0]`.

As you can see, `d0` has room for seven more results; and some lanes of the `VPADD` operations have been working with junk data.  It would be better if you could fetch more data at once, and feed that additional work in as you go so that none of the arithmetic is wasted.

---

**EDIT**

Supposing the loop is unrolled four times; with results in `d4`, `d5`, `d6`, and `d7`; the constant mentioned earlier should be loaded into, say, `d30` and `d31`, and then some `q` register arithmetic can be used:

```
VAND q0, q2, q15
VAND q1, q3, q15

VPADD.u8 d0, d0, d1
VPADD.u8 d2, d2, d3
VPADD.u8 d0, d0, d2
VPADD.u8 d0, d0, d0
```

With the final result in d0[0..3], or simply the 32-bit value in d0[0].

There seem to be lots of registers free to unroll it further, but I don't know how many of those you'll use up on other calculations.

Comment: Actually this algorithm must be part of a cycle of type "for (i = 0; i <32; i ++, center +16)" but also the values ​​that I have assumed center[0 ... 15] are actually calculated inside the loop, so I thought I first calculate center [0 ... 15] and then compute the algorithm. Or I should first calculate all the 16*32 values ​​of center[], and then join together several cycles of the algorithm under consideration. This way the second part is unrolled a little and MAYBE can compensate the split of the algorithm in 2 separate cycles.

Answer (score 0):

1. load a d register with the value 0x8040201008040201
2. vand with the result of vclt
3. vpaddl.u8 from 2)
4. vpaddl.u16 from 3)
5. vpaddl.u32 from 4)
6. store the lowest single byte from 5)

Comment: Why would you use `vpaddl` when the final result can't be longer than a byte?

Comment: This way, the other bytes aren't filled with junks. The OP wants to store just a byte to memory for now, but in case of returning in form of a 32bit value is required or so, no extra computing is required. And vpaddl dosen't consume more cycles than vpadd.

Comment: Actually this algorithm must be part of a cycle of type "for (i = 0; i <32; i ++, center +16)" but also the values ​​that I have assumed center[0 ... 15] are actually calculated inside the loop, so I thought I first calculate center [0 ... 15] and then compute the algorithm. Or I should first calculate all the 16*32 values ​​of center[], and then join together several cycles of the algorithm under consideration. This way the second part is unrolled a little and MAYBE can compensate the split of the algorithm in 2 separate cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Start with expressing the parallelism *explicitly* to begin with:

```
int /* bool, whatever ... */ val[8] = {
    center[0] < center[1],
    center[2] < center[3],
    center[4] < center[5],
    center[6] < center[7],
    center[8] < center[9],
    center[10] < center[11],
    center[12] < center[13],
    center[14] < center[15]
};
d[i] = extract_mask(val);
```

The shifts are equivalent to a "mask move", as you want each comparison to result in a single bit.

The comparison of the above sixteen values can be done by first doing a structure load (`vld2.8`) to split adjacent bytes into two `uint8x8_t`, then the parallel compare. The result of that is a `uint8x8_t` with either `0xff` or `0x00` in the bytes. You want one bit of each, in the respective bit position.

That's a "mask extract"; on Intel SSE2, that'd be `MASKMOV` but on Neon, no direct equiv exists; three `vpadd` as shown above (or see [SSE _mm_movemask_epi8 equivalent method for ARM NEON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870910/sse-mm-movemask-epi8-equivalent-method-for-arm-neon) for more on this) are a suitable substitute.