# C++ std::countr_zero() in SIMD 128/256/512 (find position of least significant 1 bit in 128/256/512-bit number)

Tags: c++, c++20, simd, avx512, sse2

If I have 128 or 256 or 512 bit memory region, how can I find number of consecutive zero bits starting from least significant bit (left-most byte). I can do:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/WaGP4zcsv)

```cpp
#include <bit>
int CountRZero512(uint64_t const * ptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        if (ptr[i] != 0)
            return i * 64 + std::countr_zero(ptr[i]);
    return 512;
}
```

As you can see I used [std::countr_zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_zero) function of C++20. Actually I generalized this std::countr_zero() function to 512-bit case.

But is it possible to do it really fast using 128/256/512-bit SIMD instructions (i.e. SSE2, AVX-2, AVX-512).

Especially this question is actual if I have a really huge array of 512-bit numbers, i.e. they are located in adjacent entries of array.

As a side second question, I wonder how to check fast if 128/256/512-bit SIMD register is equal to zero (all zero bits). Why? Because it happens in my task that great part of 512-bit numbers are totally zero (lets say half of all numbers are zero), hence I'd like to optimize my `CountRZero512()` function above to have a shortcut branch that checks if 512 bits are all zeros and immediately returns 512 as answer.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Efficiently find least significant set bit in a large array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67605508) - I don't think AVX-512 fundamentally changes what you'd do, just the details like replacing `vpcmpeqd` against a zeroed vector + `vpmovmskb` with `vptestmd` / `kmov`.  (Or `kortest` in a loop to check pairs of vectors).  I'm not sure `vplzcntd` would be useful.  If someone wants to write an AVX-512 version, it should probably get added as an answer on the linked duplicate.  (If I do, I'll add it to my answer).