# Why doesn't gas recognize vqmovn on arm64?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, gnu-assembler, neon

I have a 128 bit vector consisting of a comparison mask, eg

`ffff 0000 ffff ffff 0000 0000 0000 ffff`

My end goal is to transform this into a mask that looks like (one byte, binary)

`10110001`

I'm trying to do this in ARM assembly.

First thing I want to do is to try and narrow the vector with vqmovn.s16

`vqmovn.s16 v0, v0`

But the assembler doesn't recognize that instruction.

`Error: unknown mnemonic vqmovn.s16`

Comment: `VQMOVN` appears in the AArch32 section of the ARMv8 architecture reference manual, so I don't think you can use it on arm64.  There may be an equivalent called something else.

Comment: Maybe `SQXTN` is what you want?

Comment: I think so, I'll try it and update.

Comment: One approach might be `NEG`, `USHL` by `0x00070006000500040003000200010000`, and then `ADDV`.

Comment: There's a trick to this: load a vector containing a `0x0080 0040 0020 0010 0008 0004 0002 0001` mask, and it with the comparison mask and compute a horizontal sum (I think it's `addhl`?).

Comment: There are some other Q&As about the problem you're trying to solve, e.g: [SSE \_mm\_movemask\_epi8 equivalent method for ARM NEON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11870910)  (except that's for 8-bit elements)